# How to properly use locations in Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have 2 APIs (one built with Flask and the other one with FastAPI):

```
-- home
   -- app_flask
          main_flask.py
   -- app_fastapi
          main_fastapy.py
```

I defined a get endpoint in both files:

**main_flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello_flask")
def hello():
    return {"result": "Welcome to Flask"}
```

**main_fastapi.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello_fastapi")
def hello():
    return {"result": "Welcome to FastAPI"}
```

The first one runs on port 8000 and the second one on port 8001

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {here_my_IP};
    location /flask_app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /fastapi_app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

But once everything is running, when I access to

```
http://myIP/flask_app/hello_flask
```

or

```
http://myIP/fastapi_app/hello_fastapi
```

I get this error:

```
{"error":["404 - Resource Not Found"]}
```

I don't get this error if I use location / {} instead of location /app {} on the default Nginx file and then I access to

```
http://myIP/hello_fastapi (for example in the case of the first API)
```

So I conclude that I am incorrectly routing the apps on the defaul configuration Nginx file.

How should I do it?

Comment: I am using `server_name` together with dns set at `etc\hosts` but not sure this is best approach. I will do some research but probably someone will answer you first.

Comment: just a tentative have you tried `location /flask_app/` using `/` at the end?